# MySQL count row for distinct date distinct id

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

How can I make the first 4 rows become one row, and add one more column to state the value 4? The first four rows are same id and date but with different time. No `JOINS` are needed because this operation is just on one table.

[image: Figure]

Including time column:

[image: Including time column]

Comment: Please show your table schema, your attempt at a query, and the output you are trying to achieve. You haven't given us much to go on.

Comment: I have edit the question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the rows with an aggregate function, `count` in this case.

```
SELECT id, date, count(id)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id, date
```

The `GROUP BY id, date` clause means that we will count rows where the id and the date is the same.